# How to properly pull out records constrained by a date calculation from a joined table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime, join, where-clause, having

I have the following result from the following query:

```
SELECT users.ID, user_registered, post_date, post_type
FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON users.ID = post_author
ORDER BY ID, user_registered, post_date, post_type

  ID   user_registered          post_date      post_type
---+-----------------+------------------+--------------+
   1    6/18/2012 4:04     6/18/2012 4:04           page
   1    6/18/2012 4:04     6/18/2012 4:04           post
   1    6/18/2012 4:04    6/18/2012 10:32  nav_menu_item
   1    6/18/2012 4:04    6/18/2012 10:32  nav_menu_item
   1    6/18/2012 4:04    6/18/2012 10:32  nav_menu_item
   1    6/18/2012 4:04    6/18/2012 10:32  nav_menu_item
   1    6/18/2012 4:04    6/18/2012 10:32  nav_menu_item
   1    6/18/2012 4:04    6/18/2012 10:33  nav_menu_item
   1    6/18/2012 4:04    6/18/2012 10:48     attachment
   1    6/18/2012 4:04    6/19/2012 10:32     attachment
   1    6/18/2012 4:04     6/30/2012 6:49  nav_menu_item
   1    6/18/2012 4:04     6/30/2012 7:04  nav_menu_item
   1    6/18/2012 4:04      7/1/2012 7:39     attachment
   1    6/18/2012 4:04    7/13/2012 10:00           page
   1    6/18/2012 4:04    7/20/2012 18:18           page
   1    6/18/2012 4:04    7/21/2012 16:37           post
   1    6/18/2012 4:04    7/23/2012 14:15           page
   1    6/18/2012 4:04    7/31/2012 15:12           post
   1    6/18/2012 4:04      8/1/2012 8:47     attachment
   2   6/19/2012 10:05              NULL            NULL
   6    6/29/2012 4:47    6/19/2012 10:11     attachment
   6    6/29/2012 4:47    6/19/2012 10:15     attachment
   6    6/29/2012 4:47    6/19/2012 10:17     attachment
   6    6/29/2012 4:47    6/19/2012 10:20     attachment
   6    6/29/2012 4:47    6/19/2012 10:22     attachment
   6    6/29/2012 4:47     6/28/2012 0:00       employee
   6    6/29/2012 4:47     6/29/2012 0:00       employee
   6    6/29/2012 4:47      8/1/2012 0:00       employee
   6    6/29/2012 4:47      8/2/2012 0:00       employee
   6    6/29/2012 4:47      8/2/2012 0:00       employee
   6    6/29/2012 4:47      8/2/2012 0:00       employee
   7    7/7/2012 16:52    7/31/2012 14:26           post
  20   7/21/2012 14:48    7/21/2012 21:53           post
  20   7/21/2012 14:48    7/22/2012 12:50           post
  21   7/27/2012 14:56              NULL            NULL
```

- `ID`: user id. unique, primary key
- `user_registered`: datetime when the user became a part of the site
- `post_date`: datetime when the post was created by the user
- `post_type`: post type of post created by the user

  1. I need to get the number of days since the user last made an `employee` post (`post_date` where `post_type = 'employee'`).
  2. If the user hasn't made an `employee` post yet, then I need to get the number of days since the user registered (`user_registered`).

**REQUIREMENT**

I need to get just the `ID` of all users

1. whose latest `employee` post date is e.g. `< 7` days or `>= 14` days, or `BETWEEN 6 AND 14` as needed; OR
2. if the user does not have an `employee` post, get the user who registered `< 7` days or `>= 14` days, or `BETWEEN 6 AND 14` as in #1.

I tried the following query for a `< 7` case:

```
SELECT users.ID
FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON users.ID = post_author
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MIN(DATEDIFF(NOW(), IFNULL(post_date, user_registered))) < 7
```

and it yields the `ID`s 1, 6 and 7 as expected, because:

1. the user (6) who has an `employee` post does NOT have any other post of other `post_type`s; and
2. the users (1, 7) who don't have an `employee` post got their calculations from their `user-registered` date.

but then this query breaks when

1. the user who HAS an `employee` post ALSO HAS other `post_type`s

because I can't limit the date calculations to posts of `employee` `post_type` only. If a user has a `post` or a `page` or an `attachment` that is, say, 2 days more recent than his latest `employee`, the date calculation will return the result from the `post` or `page` or `attachment` instead.

So I tried to include `WHERE post_type = 'employee'`, but then only `ID` 6 is ever returned, because all the other users don't have an `employee` post. So I lose #2 of my requirement.

How do I go about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

You can use a [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expression within the aggregate function `MIN` to derive the minimum date difference across only `post_date`s where `post_type` is 'employee'. If there are no `post_type`s with 'employee' for a particular user, use his/her registered date instead for the comparison.

```
SELECT    a.ID
FROM      users a
LEFT JOIN posts b ON a.ID = b.post_author
GROUP BY  a.ID
HAVING    IFNULL(
              MIN(CASE b.post_type WHEN 'employee' THEN DATEDIFF(NOW(), b.post_date) END),
              DATEDIFF(NOW(), MIN(a.user_registered))
          ) < 7
```

Comment: hm.. this returns an empty result set.. workin on it til i can make it work.. any other idea? thanks much

Comment: thanks for the edit. i know we're almost there.... will keep you posted. lemme know if anythin else comes up. thanks mucho

Comment: @AnaBan, what data types are your data types for the date columns? In your example result, that doesn't look like valid DATETIME data.

Comment: @AnaBan, okay, I'm going to test with SQLFiddle, and I'll get back to you.

Comment: btw, it should also be a `DATEDIFF` for the `user_registered` scenario (sorry if that wasn't clear in the question..) anyways, i ran another test, for user 6 with an `employee` post type, the `HAVING` clause is still returning the `DATEDIFF` from `user_registered` and not `post_date`.

Comment: ok, i've been running tests, everything is A-OK in terms of the `DATEDIFF`s, except that the `HAVING` clause is always returning the `DATEDIFF` from `post_date` even if there's a legit `DATEDIFF` for `post_date`. seems like it's ALWAYS defaulting to the `NULL` part of the `IFNULL`... :/ that help?

Comment: hm.. so it does on your fiddle. but in my local, i can't get the 2 `DATEDIFF` for user 6... but so glad to see it's workin on the fiddle. i'll have to keep diggin for what's up wit my local dataset. thanks much, please lemme know if you think of anything to check why i'm always gettin gthe `NULL` part of `IFNULL`. thanks again. you epic you.. lol

Comment: ok, got it to work now. misspelled post_type. argh. hello dawn snack! pizza and 22 hrs of no sleep don't make good spellers. thanks again, dude. yer a1!

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of adding `post_type = 'employee'` condition in where clause add on `join` clause will solve your problem.

```
SELECT users.ID
FROM users 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN posts 
         ON users.ID = post_author AND 
            post_type = 'employee'
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MIN(DATEDIFF(NOW(), IFNULL(post_date, user_registered))) < 7
```

Comment: hm, this returned an empty set. :(

Comment: check for your data again. for data try having condition as < 1 also.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a correct answer as per your other constraints - What if you add a default post when an employee registers ? Will it simplify your headache ?

Comment: unfortunately, i've no control over the database. can just pull records from it. :/

Comment: hmnn... as expected ..... can you describe both tables completely in the question or comment ?